# Block cookies from specific domain

Tags: safari, cookies

I would like to configure Safari to block cookies from specific domains, but looking at the settings I couldn't find any option. Then I searched for extensions that could implement this feature, having no success with that either.

Is there any way to block specific cookies?

Comment: Depending on the domain, a plugin like ghostery might help. It doesn't let you block arbitrary domains, but it maintains a list of trackers from all sorts of sites and blocks them for you.

Comment: Yes, I used Ghostery for a while. However what I really want it to be able to block other domains.

Answer (score 1):

[SweetP Productions Cookie](https://sweetpproductions.com) was created for this purpose. Cookies can be configured individually. One can keep cookies from selected domains and remove the remainder via configurable methods such as browser quit, timer, at login, et al. Removal can be accomplished via a secure standard: US DoD 5220.22-M.

Cookie also can be configured to delete cache, history, favicons, previews, form values, downloads, and more.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a connection manager like Little Snitch to block access to domains of your choice.  It's not from within Safari, but it'll work perfectly - even system-wide.  However, Little Snitch and its competitors aren't free, but they do have trials.

Comment: how is this going to block just cookies, if you block the domain ?

Comment: Right... what does Little Snitch have to do with cookies?  If there is some hidden way to do it with Little Snitch, then please share.

Comment: I believe with Little Snitch what you'd be doing is block *outgoing* connections to specific sites.  In other words, you'd block traffic from the computer to facebook.com, but Little Snitch won't stop a facebook.com cookie being saved to the computer.